# How do I pass a variable from a custom module to a template defined in a theme?

Tags: theming

I have a theme installed to my Drupal website. The theme contains templates for both page--front.html.twig and page.html.twig.
The content of the *page--front.html.twig* file is the following.

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div id="page">
    <header id="header" class="header" role="banner" aria-label="{{ 'Site header'|t }}">
      <div class="section layout-container clearfix">
        {{ page.secondary_menu }}
        {{ page.header }}
        {{ page.primary_menu }}
        <div class="navigation-toggler"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
      </div>
    </header>
    {% if page.highlighted %}
      <div class="highlighted">
        <aside class="layout-container section clearfix" role="complementary">
          {{ page.highlighted }}
        </aside>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% if page.featured_top %}
      <div class="featured-top">
        <aside class="featured-top__inner section layout-container clearfix" role="complementary">
          {{ page.featured_top }}
        </aside>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div id="main-wrapper" class="layout-main-wrapper layout-container clearfix">
      <div id="main" class="layout-main clearfix">

        {{ page.breadcrumb }}
        <main id="content" class="column main-content" role="main">
          <section class="section">
            <a id="main-content" tabindex="-1"></a>
            {{ page.front_page }}      
          </section>
        </main>       

        {% if page.bottom %}
          {{ page.bottom }}
        {% endif %}             
      </div>       
    </div>

    <footer class="site-footer">
      <div class="layout-container">
        {% if page.footer_first or page.footer_second or page.footer_third %}
          <div class="footer-top">
            <div class="footer-top-inner">
              {{ page.footer_first }}
              {{ page.footer_second }}
              {{ page.footer_third }}
            </div>
          </div>
        {% endif %}

        {% if page.footer_left or page.footer_right %}
          <div class="footer-bottom">
            <div class="footer-bottom-inner">
              {{ page.footer_left }}
              {{ page.footer_right }}
            </div><!-- /.footer-bottom-inner -->
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>

{% if social %}
  <ul class="social-links">
    {% if social.facebook %}
      <li class="facebook"><a href="{{ social.facebook }}"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    {% endif %}

    {% if social.twitter %}
      <li class="twitter"><a href="{{ social.twitter }}"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    {% endif %}

    {% if social.pinterest %}
      <li class="pinterest"><a href="{{ social.pinterest }}"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
    {% endif %}        

    {% if social.google %}
      <li class="google"><a href="{{ social.google }}"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></a></li>
    {% endif %}            

    {% if social.youtube %}
      <li class="youtube"><a href="{{ social.youtube }}"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
    {% endif %}    
  </ul>
{% endif %}

{% if to_top %}
  <div id="to-top">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

How should I add the *page* variable?
That is being used throughout the template from a custom module I created. I think I need to use some sort of hook like `hook_preprocess_html()`, but I am not quite sure how to proceed.

Answer (score -1):

In my *.module* file inside my_module, I added the following:

```
function business_listing_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  //check if current page is front page
  if (\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage()){
      $front_page = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getRegions('front_page');    
    foreach (\Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getRegions() as $region) {
      if (!isset($variables['page'][$region])) {
        $variables['page'][$region] = [];
      }
    }
  }
```